# How to update 'number' of items added to cart pop up?

Tags: cart, magento-1, mini-cart

When I add an item to cart, it is getting displayed in cart pop up. But the numer of item is not getting upadted. Below is my coding to display the items in cart pop up. Someone please guide me to update the number when the product is added to cart.

```
 <?php $cartitem = $this->getRecentItems() ?>       
        <?php if(count($items)): ?>
                <?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems(); ?>
                    <?php foreach($cartItems as $_item): ?>
                            <?php $options = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct()); ?>
                            <?php $isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();?>
                            <?php $product = $_item->getProduct(); ?>
                            <?php echo "<ul> <li class='item'>"; ?>                                           
                            <span class="cart-img"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(50, 50); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a></span>
                            <span class="cart-name"><?php echo $_item->getName(); ?>

                            <?php 
                                foreach($options['attributes_info'] as $key => $value){ 
                                    echo ':'.$value['value'];
                                } 
                            ?>
                            </span>
                            <span class="cart-qty"><strong><?php echo $_item->getQty();?> X</strong></span>
                            <span class="cart-price"><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                                    <?php $url=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$_item->getId())); ?>
                            <span class="cart_item_delete" ><a href="<?php echo $url ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a></span>

                            <?php echo "</li></ul>" ?>  
                    <?php endforeach; ?> 
     <?php else: ?>
    <p class="empty"> <?php /*echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.')*/ ?>
    <div class="text-center">
                <h3 class="mini-cart-empty fontsize18 no-margin-btm">
                         Your Shopping Cart is empty.
               </h3>
               <h4 class="mini-cart-empty fontsize15">
                 Start shopping!
                </h4>
    </div>
    </p>
<?php endif ?>


<div class="view_cart"><a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl("checkout/cart"); ?>'>View Cart</a></div>
```

The number should be added between the brackets of below image

[image]

Comment: Do you update your item using ajax?

Comment: can you share your url ?